# Javascript function returns NaN, probably scope issue

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code and particularly a function that returns an array of functions. The issue is when I call functions in this array the results is always NaN while should be a valid number. Is it probably related to the scope?

```js
var arr = [ Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ];
var square = function (x) { return x * x; };


function makeSquareFns(arr, square) {
var fns = [];
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    fns.push(function() {
        return square(arr[i]);
    });
}
return fns;
}

var funcs = makeSquareFns(arr, square);
console.log(funcs[0]()); // IT RETURNS NaN
```

Comment: Change `var i` to `let i`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks it is correct, Can you explain me why?

Comment: `let` has lexical scope while `var` does not. Using `var`, each anonymous function (whose execution is delayed) will contain a reference to the original incremented variable `i` whose value is `arr.length` by the time `return square(arr[i]);` is executed, and `arr[arr.length]` is `undefined` and `undefined * undefined` is `NaN`

Comment: You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of a for loop. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q14k2uv9/1/)

Comment: `var arr = [ Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ];
var square = function (x) { return x * x; };


function makeSquareFns(arr, square) {
var fns = [];
arr.forEach( function(d){
    fns.push(function() {
        return square(d);
    });
})
return fns;
}

var funcs = makeSquareFns(arr, square);
console.log(funcs[0]()); // IT RETURNS NaN`